# Missing pulse detector that will output low when the input is 0v

Tags: switches, pulse, 5v

I need a missing pulse detector that will output low(0v) when the input is 0v instead 0f 5v.

Here is a link to a standard missing pulse detector
http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-555missing.html
The window is determined by the resistor and capacitor R x C, for this exaple it's 1k and 10uf so the window is 10ms.

I will be using a pulse as an input for a switch. If there is a pulse, switch is on, if the line is disconnected or missing pulse, switch is off.

Here is a picture of the desired output
[image]

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYbuzI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Suggested timing diagram of required response for OP to edit.*

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a design request website, please do some research and come back with specific design questions, not a project briefing.

Comment: (1) What is "_the standard missing pulse detector_"? (Link and schematic.) (2) How can you detect "_no missing pulses_"? (3) You have not mentioned frequency and time response of the circuit. If pulse is missing for how long? Please edit the question and ask it properly (with your attempts to date).

Comment: The circuit you linked to seems to meet your requirements. If not then please create a timing diagram of your desired response.

Comment: Timing diagrams need to be aligned vertically so you can see the time relationship between the signals. A good timing diagram will show all the possible conditions on the one diagram. I've added one into your post that you can edit. You don't seem to have realised that you can't predict a missing pulse - the output will remain on at least until the maximum expected off time has elapsed (indicated by "timeout" on the diagram).

Comment: If I invert the input this should solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a *retriggerable one-shot*.  The 74hc123 will work with 5V logic.

Comment: So how would i configure this IC?

Comment: @UmarMahmood -- frankly, I don't understand your question enough to tell you.  A retriggerable one-shot will do exactly what the figure marked "Suggested timing diagram of required response for OP to edit" does by just using the appropriate capacitor and using "in" as the trigger.  I don't understand any of the figures above that.

Comment: Sorry let me elaborate further, I would connect the input to both of the A and B inputs on the IC correct?

Comment: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT123.pdf  you have three inputs.  Two of them will be tied high or low, and one will be your signal.  Use Table 3 to figure it out.  The answer depends on if you need a positive edge trigger or negative edge trigger.

Comment: OK so for example I would make not1A low and not1RD high, 1B the positive triggered input would be my signal input. As long as there is a pulse in the interval r x c, I should get 5v out, otherwise 0v?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same design requirements, so I designed the circuit in 2 stages. First stage is usual watchdog timer. And second stage is missing pulse detector.

So in first stage Watchdog circuit is going to detect any delay in pulse and it'll output reset signal with some frequency. If watchdog input (arriving pulses) is correct it's going to output 5V.

In the second stage when you give 5V as a input it's going to give output 0V, and if you give reset signal (with specific frequency. I used TPS3430) its going to output 5V , so if you invert this output, it'll satisfy your design requirements.